# Is it possible to render a SingleEmailMessage with one object, and parent it to another object?

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage

For example: I have a template with the object A and Contact. I'll use the `Messaging`'s method `renderStoredEmailTemplate` to render the `SingleEmailMessage`, but I want the message to be parented to a record that is a different object, B.

Usually we would use the `setWhatId` method to set the object, and the platform would automatically attach the email message to the specified record. But I want the email to be attached to another record instead.

Comment: You could try with separate instances. Use one to generate the body contents and then on the other call `setHtmlBody` and `setPlainTextBody`. Same for subject, etc.

Comment: I didn't understand how this could help me in this situation. I mean, I need to generate the email with the template for object A, but attach the message to object B. By using `setSaveAsActivity` I'm forced to use `setWhatId`, which will override the related object, no?